# Adobe Molehill download link

Tags: flash, adobe

Where can I download the Molehill API / library from and what else do I need to get it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has some helpful information for getting started with Molehill, using either the Flex SDK or Flash Professional:

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flash_Player_Incubator#System_Requirements

Answer (score 1):

You need the Flash Player Incubator from here:

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/

Follow the Getting Started links at the bottom of the page to get it running.

---

More about the Molehill APIs:

- [“Molehill” 3D APIs for Flash Player and AIR](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/incubator/features/molehill.html)
- [Thibault Imbert on Molehill](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=2555)